# A message for the future. do you think future humans will be able to translate this?

Tags: language

Fastest one who translates the message into english wins this contest! (and answer question in title please)

[image: what the ? a message for future generations or just cr*p?]

Comment: Is there any good reason to post that message as an image rather than as text? I get the impression that those characters are from the Unicode character set. Does the glyph (the font) really matter? In this case can we have a larger, sharper image please? Else can we have the message as text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This text is written in

> Webdings characters which I use this [sheet](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52b5f43ee4b02301e647b446/t/56242665e4b0b08cacee76ed/1445209702919/Webding+Wingding+Icon+Cheat+Sheet+Character+Map+Symbols?format=1500w) to compare it to the english characters.

The first part, I got:

> This sentence is completely sense- and useless lol.

I don't get the

> "sense-" part.

Is it a part of the riddle or did I do something wrong?

The second one I got:

> If you encoded this sentence, you’re genius.

Is this correct?

> Do you think future humans will be able to translate this?

I can't seem to find any connection between this question and the text.
So I will take a wild guess and say

> Yes, if Webdings are still around and not forgotten.

Maybe someone else will find a better answer than me.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: (Rot13) Gur grkg vf jevggra va jroqvatf, V genafyngrq vg vagb ratyvfu.
Ohg V'z fgvyy abg fher ng nyy nobhg gur gvgyr fb V whfg gbbx n jvyq thrff.

Comment: Can you amend your answer so as to add those details, please? Can you also tell us how you __translated__ it?

Comment: Ok, I have added some explanation.

Comment: Thank you @Kevorobin. Your decoding looks fine. To answer your question: rot13(gur frafr- cneg vf n fubeg sbe frafryrff (gur -yrff sebz hfryrff vf bzvggrq))